# My Android Application Is Giving Fragment Not Attached To Activity Error.

Tags: android

//Here Is My Code
*My target is to add a custom listview on fragment and fire it on activity creation*

// FragmentSongs.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentSongs extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    
    ListView listview;
     String[] Songs=getResources().getStringArray(R.string.songs);
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
            MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(),Songs);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            View myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container,false);
            return myview;
           }
    
          
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Songs[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
    }   
    
}
```

//  MyAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context context;
    String[] songs;
    
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,String[] songs) {
        super(context,R.layout.songlist_row);
        this.context=context;
        this.songs=songs;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlist_row, null);
        }
        
        TextView tv1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText(songs[position]);
        return convertView;
        
    }
    }
```

// MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.print("Reached");
        FragmentSongs songs=new FragmentSongs();
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment1,songs);
        transaction.commit();
       
        
    }
}
```

// activitymain.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activitylayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="android.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

//
```

> this is the name of my fragment which i want to attach to activitymain

fragment_songs.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <ListView
        android1:id="@+id/listView1"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="0dp"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

// songlist_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#1A237E" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:background="#C5CAE9"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#C5CAE9"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#C5CAE9"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check This-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366596/android-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity-webview    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262994/asyctask-throwing-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of inserting a fragment of an activity and you are using both at the same time.

**The first way is:**
Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.
But in this case the fragment will be fixed on the activity like a view.

**The second form is:**
Programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.
In this case you can add the fragment at any time to the activity, replace it with another fragment, remove the fragment when you want.

You can see what I'm telling you watching this link to the Android developer and looking "Adding a fragment to an activity".

[Fragments Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html)

Note: If you decide to programmatically add the fragment do not have to reference it in the XML Activity. On the other hand these lines would thus:

```
    FragmentSongs songs=new FragmentSongs();
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.content,songs);
    transaction.commit();
```

**R.id.content:** It is the id of the container in which you add the fragment programmatically in your case on the activitymain.xml LinearLayout. As you can see you did not like this but you linked the id of the fragment which is a mistake.

Well do not forget that you should not use two ways of adding the fragments so pick one and hope that what prompted you find it useful.